# What is this USAF transport aircraft from possibly the 50-60s?

Tags: aircraft-identification, us-air-force, transport-category

I came across the following image (scan of a photograph) in an archive of photographs related to the 1962 [Sino-Indian War](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sino-Indian_War).

[image]

Which particular aircraft could this be?

**Update**: This [answer](https://history.stackexchange.com/a/45671/25091) identifies it as belonging to [322d Airlift Division](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/322d_Airlift_Division).

Comment: Please provide a source for your image

Comment: @TomMcW, it's a scan of a photograph...

Comment: Is the original photo clear enough to make out the badge that’s cut off to the upper left of the door

Comment: @TomMcW, unfortunately I don't have access to the original photographs now. I actually got the scanned images and optimised them. There was minimum cropping so most probably the full badge is unavailable...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[image]
([Source](http://www.theaviationzone.com/factsheets/c130_talking_bird.asp))

[image]
([af.mil](http://www.af.mil/News/Photos/igphoto/2000929258/)) Early three-bladed version.

It's a USAF [Lockheed C-130 Hercules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lockheed_C-130_Hercules). Shown above is the same shiny livery with the painted prop line. The C-130 first flew on 23 August 1954.

Comment: Seems very close... The picture in question has a three bladed propeller. Were such propellers used?

Comment: @Kanchu - [Some C-130s](http://www.airliners.net/photo/USA-Air-Force/Lockheed-C-130D-Hercules-L-182/1125701) had 3-bladed props. Good catch.

Comment: Hmm... Some search of `USAF` and `Tibet` did result in [flights being undertaken in C-130](http://www.newsweek.com/secret-war-roof-world-165592): `...parachuting into Tibet out of the silver C-130s...`.

Comment: @Kanchu - I tried to find info on the 014, but found nothing so far.

Comment: The second image seems to give a very strong match; the set of windows on the port side with the first two ahead of wing closer than the next two, as in the picture in question...

Comment: It might be [55-014](http://www.c-130.net/aircraft-database/C-130/airframe-profile/6315/) with the 815th Troop Carrier Squadron but I can’t find verification that they participated in the Sino-Indian war

Comment: It's quite amazing that the C-130 has been around before colour photography even became common.

Comment: The first C-130 gunships were converted from A model herks, which all came with 3-bladed props (top & bottom pictures) and small external tanks outboard of engines 1 & 4 (top picture). The B model had no external tanks, and it & subsequent (up to but not including the J) had 4-bladed props (3rd picture). After the particular A’s were converted to gunships, they got the 4-blade props as well (2nd picture).

Answer (score 22):

It is indeed a C-130A. The large tail numbers indicate it's from the late 50's or early 60's. In the late 60's, the USAF went with smaller numbers forward of the passenger door. Here's a similar a/c image from C-130.net

[image: USAF C-130A #56-0545 of the 322nd AD. [photographer unknown]]

Further searching of the C-130 Aircraft Database shows the only "014" to be be s/n [55-0014](http://www.c-130.net/aircraft-database/C-130/airframe-profile/6315/). The history shows it was assigned to the 40th TAS which was part of the 322nd AD.

In 1968 it was converted to an AC-130A gunship. It is currently on display at the Museum of Aviation at Robins AFB.

[image: USAF AC-130A #55-0014, USAF photo by MSgt. Chance Babin]

Comment: Those camels on the side of the plane...